# PyQt need to throw custom widgets into a list and be able to move them around

Tags: python, pyqt, qwidget, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I have been fighting with custom widgets and lists for weeks now.

I have the ability to add a custom widget to a QListWidget. My issue is the insertItem seems to be buggy as it always drops it to the bottom of the list no matter what row I tell it to go to.

```
def AddToInitiative(self):
        creature = self.comboBoxSelectCharacter.currentText()
        if(creature):
            widget = self.NewItemWidget()

            customWidgetItem = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(self.initiativeList)
            customWidgetItem.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(400,50))
            self.initiativeList.addItem(customWidgetItem)
            self.initiativeList.setItemWidget(customWidgetItem, widget)

            widget.lineName.setText(creature)
        return

def NewItemWidget(self):
            customWidget = creature_initiative_object.InitCreatureObject()
            customWidget.btnRemove.clicked.connect(self.ItemButtonClicked)
            customWidget.btnInfo.clicked.connect(self.ItemButtonClicked)
            customWidget.btnIncreaseInitOrder.clicked.connect(self.ItemButtonClicked)
            customWidget.btnDecreaseInitOrder.clicked.connect(self.ItemButtonClicked)
            return customWidget

 def ChangeInit(self, row, direction, oldwidget):
        item = self.initiativeList.takeItem(row)

        widget = self.NewItemWidget()
        widget.lineName.setText(oldwidget.lineName.text())
        customWidgetItem = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(self.initiativeList)
        customWidgetItem.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(400,50))

        self.initiativeList.insertItem((row + direction), customWidgetItem)
        self.initiativeList.setItemWidget(customWidgetItem, widget)
        self.initiativeList.setCurrentRow(row+direction)
```

If I try to move the item up or down the list it always just goes straight to the bottom despite assigning the row number. I've output the row number and count to verify it should be saying the right row.

Do you know a way to do this with QListWidget for custom widgets that need to preserve data? Is there a better module to use?

I've looked at QListView, QBoxLayout, and a few others without being able to get it to work as well as QListWidget.

Comment: Which PyQt version are you using? Version 4, or version 5?

Comment: If you think there's a bug in Qt you should discuss it on their forums.

Comment: @jrd1 I am using pyqt4